# C# tcp socket (networkstream.read won't work with 8.1)

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I've got a program that runs a tcp socket. It runs fine on anything below windows 8.1. I've already turned off my firewall and have set everything to allow this connection.

1.First the server does run on windows 8.1
2.The client socket does connect. 
3.The client sends a string "login", to trigger the initial interaction.
   -that string does get sent.
4.The connection fails when the server setup the networkstream.read();
  -I'm not seeing anything in debugger, and again it works fine on other
  -systems

here is how the I setup the server to listen. It's pretty traditional.

//LISTENS TO CLIENT

```
 public String listen() {

            byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
            string dataFromClient = null;


            NetworkStream networkStream = this.clientSocket.GetStream();//get client input


         This is the line that fails{
            networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);//read client info  } -end fail

            dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);//pass client input to String
            dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));//parse to end
            //MessageBox.Show("data:" + dataFromClient);
            networkStream.Flush();
          //  networkStream.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("data:" + dataFromClient);
            return dataFromClient;
        }
```

Comment: Define "fails"... does it throw an exception? What is the exception?  Does it return no data?  looking at the code, how do you know how many bytes were returned anyways since you're not capturing the return value from Read?

Comment: That's the problem, is it breaks the try/catch. but ever time I run it from the compiler I see nothing in debug. And I've been trying this all evening. actually I do capture the data. See the Bytesform on the next line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create the buffer with clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize so change:

```
byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
```

into:

```
byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
```

end get the buffersize from this array:

```
networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, bytesFrom.Length);
```

Comment: Cageman freaking rocks. That worked like a charm. I'm logged in and pushing inventory on Windows 8. Awesome stuff.

Comment: Why does it matter that I predefine the array versus letting the client define it? I get there is an issue if the client goes out of bounds, but it seems it should work and does work on xp, vista, and 7. Is ths more an example of windows 8.1 engineers saying getting it fromthe client is a better practice, therefore you are no longer allowed to predefine the array?