# NetworkStream.Read throws no exception

Tags: c#, tcp, networkstream

I cannot get this example to run:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The only thing Ive changed with their code is to put everything in the main method, and my port name of course. I Can connect to my server, and even send data. But on the line

```
Int32 bytes = networkStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
```

The program stops running without an exception. How can microsoft own code not work? My server doesnt send anything yet, but I dont think that should matter? (It recieves perfectly though.) Ive Read something that you cannot se exceptions in other threads, but I dont have any. 
I also tried this thread: 
[C# tcp socket (networkstream.read won't work with 8.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272106/c-sharp-tcp-socket-networkstream-read-wont-work-with-8-1)

It doesnt work. I run win 7 thoguh. But I wish this to work an all new windows.

Comment: Read is a synchronous call. What are you sending from the server?

Comment: Read() will block/stop, waiting until some data is received. As a workaround to this blocking, you can add `if(networkStream.IsDataAvailable)` before reading. This way, it should be never blocking.

Comment: @ThariqNugrohotomo and what if it returns false? That does not mean there is no data! IsDataAvailable doesn't work for this.

Comment: @usr From my past experience, it works though. If it's still returning false, probably you forgot to flush the data, maybe the received data is still too small, or the underlying Stream implementation is buggy.

Comment: Or, the data is still in the network and will arrive soon. It can't work.

Comment: @usr "data is still in the network and will arrive soon" true, that also VERY possible. But in my "past experience" mentioned earlier, the requirement was a bit different from usual. If I remember correctly, we need to reduce the number of thread, thus we put some processing on reader thread if it's not currently busy receiving the data.

Comment: This is a polling solution. That can work, but it is less efficient and leads to convoluted code. It is better to always have one read IO outstanding and to use async IO for that. Instead of polling you are alerted of any event (though IO completion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NetworkStream.Read` blocks until data is available, the connection is closed (it will return `0` in that case) or an exception occurs. It is designed that way.

If your server would send data, your client program would continue and be able to process the response.

Comment: Appear to be the case. Very strange behavior I must say. There seems to be a change in execution of this command also, because old examples online all use something like a read in their while loop. I must now use something like while(stream.dataavailble) and then read inside the while loop.

Comment: @StaffanMattsson : There's no change in execution. The examples have `Read()` in the loop because they can probably afford the block (i.e. it's in another thread). It's always been blocking if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @StaffanMattsson : It's even stated in the `NetworkStream.Read()` documentation for as early as .NET Framework 1.1 that _**"If no data is available for reading, the NetworkStream.Read method will block until data is available."**_. Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: This blocking behavior allows `NetworkStream` to be passed into anything  expecting a `Stream`, such as `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: @StaffanMattsson imho this design is what majority developer is actually needs. We don't want it to instantly return zero data, saying that nothing is received, which if put inside loop could effectively become a busy-loop that consume extensive cpu time. The blocking behavior is saving cpu time when no data is received.

Answer (score 0):

NetworkStream.Read() is a synchronous call, it will wait till a response is received. To read data of different lengths, you can do something like below.

NOTE: I'm assuming server is sending only one response for a request.

```
private string GetResponse(string command)
{
    //Send request
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient(HOST, PORT);
    Byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

    //Read response
    data = new Byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    String response = String.Empty;
    stream.ReadTimeout = READ_TIMEOUT;
    while (!response.EndsWith(RESPONSE_END))
    {
        int bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        response += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
    }
    response = response.Remove(response.Length - RESPONSE_END.Length);
    stream.Close();
    client.Close();

    //Return
    return response;
}
```

Comment: This has a bug because it can read multiple messages at a time, or one message plus a partial one.

Comment: @usr True, if multiple responses are sent by server. In this example, I assume server is sending only one response for a request.

Comment: Right, I did not think of that possibility.

Comment: @usr Thanks for taking a more detailed look at the code.